# android search dialog customization

Tags: android, search, android-theme

After several searches I couldn't figure out how to customize the search dialog (the top search bar that appears when you click the search button).  I want to change the background color of the search bar.  I got articles on how to customize a title bar.  But that doesn't work for search bar.

Any helpful pointers please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it's not customizable: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/ZqZ-KZPLGtk

Comment: Thank you fiddler.  It looks like non-customizable.  That makes the look of the screen a bit weird.  Will accept the answer if no one else has any other suggestions on the topic. Thank you once again.