# android Search Interface - how to remove app icon when onSearchRequested() called

Tags: android, searchview, android-search

[image: expanding SearchView widget on ActionBar]

On `MainActivity.class`, i call a search dialog by `onSearchRequested()`. That how it shows up as image above.

I want to removed that home/app icon but no luck. Please don't confuse that i want to removed home/app icon on action bar. No, this is a Search dialog which i declared on `SearchActivity.class`

```
public class SearchableActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchable);

    // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        doMySearch(query);
    }
}}
```

and on `xml/searchable.xml`

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:hint="@string/search_hint"
android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer">
```

on `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                   android:value=".SearchableActivity"/>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SearchableActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

This is `v21/styles.xml` i used

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/orange</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/darkorange</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/brown</item>
    <!--   title bar text color -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!--   no action bar -->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>
```

Another question if you don't mind. As i declare `darkorange` color for the status bar, and it works well. But when `onSearchRequested()` is called, the status bar is changed to black (as image above). How can i fix that too?

Comment: What did you already try to remove the icon?

Comment: a bunch of methods `<item name="android:displayOptions"></item>`, `<item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>`, `getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);`, `getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);`, but doesn't work

Comment: Try it in the emulator (maybe even with different ones) to see whether the problem occurs only on your device or on other ones as well.

Comment: @laph Did you manage to solve it? Having the same issue.

Comment: According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936674/android-search-dialog-customization), its not customizable.

Answer (score 1):

Try either according to your scenario

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

or

```
getActionBar().setIcon(new 
ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
```

Comment: I don't use ActionBarSherlock, but it doesn't work anyway. How did your answer already get '+1' within 5 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution can be to make the icon transparent when the search has focus with:

```
getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
```

Then you can restore it by calling your app icon.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove icon when onsearchrequested called. you can add android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" in option_menu xml

like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
          android:title="@string/search_title"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
          android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

you can check this [setup](https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup)

Comment: This solution will not work for SearchDialog. :(